# AngularJs directive link function testing with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to understand how the directives works and how to test the directives with jasmine. I cant test link function in directive. What I am doing wrong?

```
  it('should add class', function(){
            //digest the $rootScope
            $scope.$digest();
                expect(element.hasClass('test')).toBe(true);
            });
    });
```

I am trying to write a test that ensures that the element has an added class.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4FgL3uHW8oTuU1GdGCPh?p=preview

I'm receiving error **element.addClass it not a function.**

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your directive link function. The first argument is the `scope`. The `element` comes the second:

```
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<i>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass('test');
        }
    }
}])
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/u6u3SYCZJ4rgQSVD85xT?p=preview